# SignalR - Show msg if hub is online

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I'm building a chat, where clients can chat with a support team.

All clients websites have a chat. And the support team have one site. When The support team log in to there site. The hub-connection gets available, and the chat is open.

But on the clients websites, how can I show a message when supportTeam start the hub: Something like:

```
alert('cht is now online');
```

My try:

ChatHub.cs

```
public void AdminJoin()
    {
        var adminUser = "Chat is now open"

        Clients.All.AdminIsOnline(adminUser);
    }
```

Code on the clients website:

```
chat.on('AdminIsOnline', function (adminUser) {
            adminHasJoined(adminUser);
        });

        function adminHasJoined(adminUser) {
            alert(adminUser);
        };
```

Code above only runs when I refresh the clients website page, and when SuppertTeam-site is online.
I want the alert to show everytime the suppoertTeam logs in. Not only on pageRefresh

Answer (score 0):

In short:
1. Inherit OnConnect method.
2. Add users to Group.
3. Create method that will inform all members of group about new group member.
4. Use JS to inform about event on client side.
Hub example:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {

        PREPP2Entities db = new PREPP2Entities();
        //Send message to chat room
        public void SendChatMessage(string gn, string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.Group(gn).addChatMessage(name, message);
            UserStatus();
        }
        //Public method that available on client side and used to update user status on user actions (e.g.Connect, disconnect
        public void UserStatus()
        {
            Clients.All.updateStatus();
        }
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            //get user data
            var x = (from a in db.Users where a.Login.Contains(Context.User.Identity.Name) select a.Role).FirstOrDefault();
            //Add to the list of online users
            if (AlreadyOnline(Context.ConnectionId) == false)
            {
                try
                {
                    UsersOnline uo = new UsersOnline();
                    uo.ConnectionID = Context.ConnectionId;
                    uo.UserName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
                    uo.UserRole = x;
                    uo.Created = DateTime.Now;
                    db.UsersOnline.Add(uo);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                            .SelectMany(y => y.ValidationErrors)
                            .Select(y => y.ErrorMessage);
                    var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
                    var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
                    throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
                }
                //User with role "User"
                if (x == 1)
                {
                    //Add user to group
                    JoinGroup(Context.ConnectionId, Context.User.Identity.Name, true);
                    var operatorName = GetOperator();
                    //Find connection id
                    var cid = (from a in db.UsersOnline where a.UserName.Contains(operatorName) & a.UserRole == 2 select a.ConnectionID).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (cid != null & !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cid))
                    {
                        //Add user to group
                        JoinGroup(cid, Context.User.Identity.Name, false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Message that nobody's here
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);
                        sb.AppendFormat("Здравствуйте {0}! ", Context.User.Identity.Name);
                        sb.Append("К сожалению сейчас наших стилистов нет в сети.<br />");
                        sb.Append("Вы можете оставить сообщение, которое будет прочитано позже.");
                        string message = sb.ToString();
                        SendChatMessage(Context.User.Identity.Name, "PREPP", message);
                    }
                }
                //Else user role belong to support team
                else
                {
                    //Find users that has this support team to talk
                    var oid = (from a in db.Users where a.Login.Contains(Context.User.Identity.Name) select a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    var u = (from a in db.UsersOnline
                             join b in db.Users on a.UserName equals b.Login
                             where a.UserRole == 1 & b.OperatorID == oid
                             select a.UserName).ToArray();
                    foreach (string n in u)
                    {
                        JoinGroup(Context.ConnectionId, n, false);
                    }
                }
            }
            UserStatus();
            return base.OnConnected();
        }
        public void JoinGroup(string connectionid, string groupName, bool send)
        {
            try
            {
                GroupInfo gi = new GroupInfo();
                gi.UserConnection = connectionid;
                gi.GroupName = groupName;
                gi.Created = DateTime.Now;
                db.GroupInfo.Add(gi);
                db.SaveChanges();
                Groups.Add(connectionid, groupName);
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                        .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
                var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
                var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
                throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
            }
            if (send == true)
            {
                var on = GetOperator();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);
                sb.AppendFormat("Здравствуйте {0}! ", Context.User.Identity.Name);
                sb.AppendFormat("Я Ваш личный стилист - {0}. ", on);
                sb.Append("Чем сегодня я могу помочь Вам?");
                string message = sb.ToString();
                SendChatMessage(groupName, on, message);
            }
            UserStatus();
        }
        public bool AlreadyOnline(string connectionid)
        {
            bool exist;
            var x = db.UsersOnline.Where(p => p.ConnectionID.Contains(connectionid)).Count();
            if (x > 0)
            {
                exist = true;
            }
            else
            {
                exist = false;
            }
            return exist;
        }
        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
            sb.AppendFormat("Пользователь {0} не в сети!", Context.User.Identity.Name);
            string message = sb.ToString();
            SendChatMessage(Context.User.Identity.Name, "PREPP", message);
            UserStatus();
            db.GroupInfo.RemoveRange(db.GroupInfo.Where(x => x.UserConnection.Contains(Context.ConnectionId)));
            db.UsersOnline.RemoveRange(db.UsersOnline.Where(x => x.UserName.Contains(Context.User.Identity.Name)));
            db.SaveChangesAsync();
            UserStatus();
            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }
        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
            sb.AppendFormat("Пользователь {0} вернулся к нам!", Context.User.Identity.Name);
            string message = sb.ToString();
            SendChatMessage(Context.User.Identity.Name, "PREPP", message);
            UserStatus();
            return base.OnReconnected();
        }
        public string GetOperator()
        {
            //Возвращаем имя оператора если он был назначен ранее
            var oid = (from a in db.Users where a.Login.Contains(Context.User.Identity.Name) select a.OperatorID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (oid.HasValue)
            {
                return db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == oid).Select(x => x.Login).SingleOrDefault();
            }
            //Выбираем и добавляем пользователю случайного оператора
            else
            {
                //выбираем всех пользователей с ролью оператора
                var opname = (from a in db.UsersOnline where a.UserRole == 2 orderby (Guid.NewGuid()) select a.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
                //Назначем пользователю оператора
                var opid = (from a in db.Users where a.Login.Contains(opname) select a.Id).SingleOrDefault();
                if (opid > 0)
                {
                    WriteOperator(Context.User.Identity.Name, opid);
                    return opname;
                }
                else
                {
                    var op = (from a in db.Users where a.Role == 2 orderby (Guid.NewGuid()) select a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    WriteOperator(Context.User.Identity.Name, op);
                    return db.Users.Where(x => x.Id == op).Select(x => x.Login).SingleOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }
         void WriteOperator(string username, int operatorid)
        {
            var uid = db.Users.Where(p => p.Login == username).Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            var a = db.Users.Find(uid);
            if (a != null)
            {
                a.OperatorID = operatorid;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else throw new Exception();
```

}
    }

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was looking for something simpler. Could I add an automatic try to reconnect to the hub to the clients-wesites if connection is not found? How would that javascript look like?

Comment: By default the SignalR client tries to reconnect as soon as the connection with the server is dropped. what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Chris The problem is I need to refresh the clients websites to connect to the hub. THIS IS THE SCENARIO: If a go to a clients website and the hub is offline, then ofcourse I'm not  getting connected. While still on the clients website, adn then start the supportSite(hub starts). Then I want to show a msg on the clients website that hub is online. Without the need of refreshing the page!

Comment: You can use the SignalR javascript connection lifetime events. Details [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#connectionlifetime). There is a stateChanged event which you can implement client-side to display whatever message you want. No need to refresh the page :)

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I will look into that. Do I need to have the onConnect, onDisconnect, onReconnect in the hub to use these lifetime events?

Comment: @user3228992, yes. OnConnect, onDisconnect you can use for add users to the list of online users or add/remove them from group.

Comment: @andrey.shedko Still having this problem: - If a go to a clients website and the hub is offline, then ofcourse I'm not getting connected. While still on the clients website, and then start the supportSite(hub starts). Then I want to show a msg on the clients website that hub is online. Without the need of refreshing clients website! Can someone please point me in the right direction to solve this? I've searched on the web for hours...

Comment: 1. Add user to group. 2. Add another user to group when he is became online. 3. Inform first connected user (or all group members) by public method using JS in his browser that new user has been added.

Comment: @user3228992 that's not doable. If your users browse to the page but the hub is down, then the only way to force the client to connect is either by refreshing the page or using a button to call the `connect();` Some things are outside our control. Maybe you can have a loop/timer implemented in javascript that attempts to reconnect if the server goes offline, but this will seriously mess with the normal SignalR workflow. A hack that could work, but a hack nonetheless

Comment: It's working on example that I gave you. Of course this need some client side magic that I did with Knockout.js